# Get the limit from $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(x\int _{\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\arctan\left(x\right)}\sin\left(t^2\right)dt\:\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, improper-integrals

Get the limit from $$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(x\int _{\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\arctan\left(x\right)}\sin\left(t^2\right)dt\:\right)$$

I figured that $\arctan(x)$ when $x$ goes to $\infty$ is $\pi/2$ so the integral would be $0$ since it goes from the same top and bottom boundaries, then it would be $\infty$ $*$ $0$.

Then I tried using L'Hopital because it is an indetermination, so I made the limit into a division of $$\frac{x}{\frac{1}{\int _{\frac{\pi \:}{2}}^{\arctan\left(x\right)}\sin\left(t^2\right)dt}}$$

and then derive top and bottom so it would be $$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\frac{\sin\left(\arctan\left(x\right)^2\right)}{x^2+1}\:}}$$ but applying then the limit to $\infty$ it is $0$, but I think it was not supposed to be that value and it was something related with $\pi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\infty}x\int_{\pi/2}^{\arctan x}\sin(t^2)\,\mathrm dt&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\int_{\pi/2}^{\arctan x}\sin(t^2)\,\mathrm dt}{\frac 1x}\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac1{1+x^2}\sin\left(\arctan^2x\right)}{-\frac1{x^2}}\\&=-\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\sin\left(\arctan^2x\right)\\&=-\sin\left(\frac{\pi^2}4\right).\end{align}

Comment: thanks, I think I should have tried doing the L'Hopital rule inverting the f(x)/q(x)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.